# how to add styling when app is mounted? vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i have a template code like this

this is my script code

```
   data () {
    return {
      loadPage: true
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.loadPage = true
  },
```

this is my styling code

```
#app{
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

I want to set a class/Id styling after it is mounted (setting their opacity to 1) Is there any simple way to accomplish this? Examples would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two solutions bound a class or bound a style.

PD: If I guess correctly you want to have a transition depending on the state of a component, you can also use vue transitions for this https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html

**Bounding a css class**

```
<template>
 <div id="app" :class={ visible: mounted }>
   <h1>app</h1>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      mounted: false
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.mounted = true;
  }
}
</script>

<style>
#app{
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.visible {
  opacity: 1;
}
</style>
```

**Bounding a style**

```
<template>
 <div id="app" :style=`mounted && 'opacity: 1;'`>
   <h1>app</h1>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      mounted: false
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.mounted = true;
  }
}
</script>

<style>
#app{
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: this code only work when i use it on my vue.app, but when i add this to other component or page.vue the style or the transition doesnt work

Comment: yeah, the problem is that you are applying the transition only to #app selector, can you edit your question adding what problem you are trying to solve? I only add the code that solve the specific issue explained in the question, if you describe what you want to achieve probably there is a a better solution

Comment: ahh okaay my bad